# Php inserting escape characters in the csv output file

Tags: php, javascript

I am using this php code to allow the user to send dojo.enchancedgrid to file and download it to his machine. The procedure works fine, but the output csv file has the escape lines for the quotes. How can I avoid php inserting those for me. The string that is passed to the function(str) is ok, but after passes through the php code is different.

My javascript code:

```
function exportCsv(){

var g = dijit.byId("grid");
g.exportGrid("csv",{
            writerArgs: {
                separator: ","
            }
            }, function(str){
                alert(str);


                    var form = document.createElement('form');
                    dojo.attr(form, 'method', 'POST');
                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    dojo.io.iframe.send({
                            url: "csv.php",
                            form: form,
                            method: "POST",
                            content: {exp: str},
                            timeout: 15000
                    });
                    document.body.removeChild(form);

                    });
```

}

My php code:

```
$time = time();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grid_$time.csv\"");
$exportedData = $_POST['exp'];
echo $exportedData;
```

Also the server is inserting some analytics code in the rows as well…
Thank you very much for the help guys.
Below is the output csv file:

Lon,Lat,Network,RouteId,Measure

-74.18143812,40.62733114,\"Named Route\",IN278,1

-73.90131905,40.75932358,\"Named Route\",IN278,25

-73.8005193,40.73819062,\"Named Route\",IN495,10

-73.82437443,40.79381815,\"Named Route\",IN678,12

-73.79087796,40.66589334,\"Named Route\",\"NY 27\",12

<-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->

<--End Of Analytics Code -->

Comment: Where/how is `$exportedData` generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can escape the quotes yourself on the client side string (Javascript) and unescape them in PHP - that way you control the whole process.
2. The reason you have the hoster's "Analytics code" is that you're using free hosting (I assume). It's not analytics but ads, added to every http response. On an HTML page they look like ads at the bottom. If you use AJAX, they just get in the way. If you're actually paying for hosting, call your hoster and ask to him to get rid of those.

Comment: echo stripslashes($exportedData); solved the problem, Thank you all

Comment: Also, i found out that the way to remove the add on by the server is to add exit; in the end of my php

Comment: Really? That removes it? Are you using a free account, or paid?

Answer (score 0):

As zerkms suggested, this is likely due to [`magic quotes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Try disabling them.

Comment: I apologize for the wrong explanation, not the quotes but the escape character \ is the problem that is being inserted.